# Creating and Writing in a Text File using DOS Command

Tags: dos

I want to know how can I create a file named e.g myfile.txt in a D:\MyFiles directory and write first & last name in it

I wrote below code for that.

```
MD D:\Workdirectory\PRIVATE\DOCUMENT\type myfile.txt First_Name Last_Name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like the following:
    `echo First_Name Last_Name > D:\MyFiles\myfile.txt`

Answer (score 5):

This would also work:

```
@echo First_Name Last_Name > D:\MyFiles\myfile.txt
```

If you want to append to the file you can do this:

```
@echo First_Name Last_Name >> D:\MyFiles\myfile.txt
```

Comment: You could also append the value of variables to the file.